# Stacking Cisco Catalyst 3850 via Fibre?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, stacking, vss, vpc

I'm working at several new network concepts for our company and the challenge is to stack at least two Catalyst 3850 over a distance of 200-300 meters. I know there are other possibilities like VSS or vPC (with other components), but I wanted to know if it's possible to stack them over distance and how this could be done.
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Is Cisco a requisite or you are open to other vendors?

Comment: Cisco is a requisite and replaces avaya switches here...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Wise is not possible without the use of stack ports and stack cables and the maximum stack cable length i deal with was CAB-SPWR-150CM which was 1.5 m . so you can't stack over this distance . and also you can make use of this discussion

[enter link description here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/can-you-stack-cisco-3750-using-ethernet-cables)

Comment: And what about "emulating" a stack via fibre? Is that possible (like a "stretched stack")?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: Sorry, but last try - is it possible with any of the catalyst series (like the 2960FX or similar)? Just to get things right

Comment: also NO . maximum length for stack cable supported in 2960 series CAB-STK-E-3M which is 3m

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what it is you're trying to achieve? Is staking a must? If not there might be another solution. If it is, why is?

Comment: stack not a must and the 2960 series and there is no similar instillation will do the same in this series and the reason that stack is only for easy management so it not affect the data switching or improve the performance  but only make the management easier little bit ,we just make it if it is possible

Answer (score 2):

This answer probably won't very useful today, but it's possible to stack 2960X via fiber. You need C2960X-FIBER-STK.